# How can I parse the src property of an iframe tag in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, iframe, nsstring

I have the following string:

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Pb55ep-DrSo?wmode=opaque&autoplay=1&fs=1&feature=oembed&showinfo=0&autohide=1&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I'd like to pull out the src property, but not exactly sure how I would parse that in Objective-C?

Comment: Did you try NSXMLParser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ugly, but it works:

```
NSString* str = @"<iframe width=\"1280\" height=\"720\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/Pb55ep-DrSo?wmode=opaque&autoplay=1&fs=1&feature=oembed&showinfo=0&autohide=1&controls=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
str = [str substringFromIndex:[str rangeOfString:@"src=\""].location+[str rangeOfString:@"src=\""].length];
str = [str substringToIndex:[str rangeOfString:@"\""].location ];
NSLog(@"Str %@",str);
```

I tested it, and it outputs:

```
2012-08-17 09:16:55.285 TEST[24413:c07] Str http://www.youtube.com/embed/Pb55ep-DrSo?wmode=opaque&autoplay=1&fs=1&feature=oembed&showinfo=0&autohide=1&controls=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the regex which fetches src property, just so if you need to verify it with some regex builder

```
src[\s]*=[\s]*"([^"]*)"
```

and here is the full code you can use in your program,

```
NSString *searchedString = @"<iframe width=\"1280\" height=\"720\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/Pb55ep-DrSo?wmode=opaque&autoplay=1&fs=1&feature=oembed&showinfo=0&autohide=1&controls=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
NSError* error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"src[\s]*=[\s]*\"([^\"]*)\"" options:0 error:&error];
NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:searchedString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchedString length])];
for ( NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches )
{
    NSString* matchText = [searchedString substringWithRange:[match range]];
    NSLog(@"match: %@", matchText);
    NSRange group1 = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"group1: %@", [searchedString substringWithRange:group1]);
}
```

Hope this helps!